# Joining Time Series Dataframes where duplicate columns contain the same values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, join, time-series

I'm trying to combine multiple dataframes that contain time series data. These dataframes can have up to 100 columns and roughly 5000 rows. Two sample dataframes are

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'SubjectID': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C'], 'Date': ['2010-05-08', '2010-05-10', '2010-05-08', '2010-05-08'], 'Test1':[1, 2, 3, 4], 'Gender': ['M', 'M', 'M', 'F'], 'StudyID': [1, 1, 1, 1]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'SubjectID': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C'], 'Date': ['2010-05-08', '2010-05-09', '2010-05-10', '2010-05-08', '2010-05-09'], 'Test2': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'Gender': ['M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'F'], 'StudyID': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]})

df1
    SubjectID   Date    Test1   Gender  StudyID
0         A     2010-05-08  1   M   1
1         A     2010-05-10  2   M   1
2         B     2010-05-08  3   M   1
3         C     2010-05-08  4   F   1

df2
    SubjectID   Date    Test2   Gender  StudyID
0   A   2010-05-08  1   M   1
1   A   2010-05-09  2   M   1
2   A   2010-05-10  3   M   1
3   B   2010-05-08  4   M   1
4   C   2010-05-09  5   F   1
```

My expected output is

```
SubjectID   Date    Test1   Gender  StudyID     Test2   
0   A   2010-05-08  1.0     M   1.0     1.0     
1   A   2010-05-09  NaN     M   1.0     2.0     
2   A   2010-05-10  2.0     M   1.0     3.0     
3   B   2010-05-08  3.0     M   1.0     4.0     
4   C   2010-05-08  4.0     F   1.0     NaN     
5   C   2010-05-09  NaN     F   1.0     5.0
```

I'm joining the dataframes by

```
merged_df = df1.set_index(['SubjectID', 'Date']).join(df2.set_index(['SubjectID', 'Date']), how = 'outer', lsuffix = '_l', rsuffix = '_r').reset_index()
```

but my output is

```
  SubjectID     Date    Test1   Gender_l    StudyID_l   Test2   Gender_r    StudyID_r
0         A     2010-05-08  1.0     M   1.0     1.0     M   1.0
1         A     2010-05-09  NaN    NaN  NaN     2.0     M   1.0
2         A     2010-05-10  2.0     M   1.0     3.0     M   1.0
3         B     2010-05-08  3.0     M   1.0     4.0     M   1.0
4         C     2010-05-08  4.0     F   1.0     NaN     NaN NaN
5         C     2010-05-09  NaN    NaN  NaN     5.0     F   1.0
```

Is there a way to combine columns while joining the dataframes if all the values in both dataframes are equal? I can do it after the merge, but that will get tedious for my large datasets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how you want to implement the logic of resolving information that may not exactly match. Had you merged several frames, I think taking the `modal` value is appropriate. Taking your `merged_df` we can resolve it as:

```
merged_df = merged_df.groupby([x.split('_')[0] for x in merged_df.columns], 1).apply(lambda x: x.mode(1)[0])

         Date Gender  StudyID SubjectID  Test1  Test2
0  2010-05-08      M      1.0         A    1.0    1.0
1  2010-05-09      M      1.0         A    NaN    2.0
2  2010-05-10      M      1.0         A    2.0    3.0
3  2010-05-08      M      1.0         B    3.0    4.0
4  2010-05-08      F      1.0         C    4.0    NaN
5  2010-05-09      F      1.0         C    NaN    5.0
```

---

Or perhaps, you want to give priority to the non-null value value in the first frame, then this is `.combine_first`.

```
df1.set_index(['SubjectID', 'Date']).combine_first(df2.set_index(['SubjectID', 'Date']))

                     Gender  StudyID  Test1  Test2
SubjectID Date                                    
A         2010-05-08      M      1.0    1.0    1.0
          2010-05-09      M      1.0    NaN    2.0
          2010-05-10      M      1.0    2.0    3.0
B         2010-05-08      M      1.0    3.0    4.0
C         2010-05-08      F      1.0    4.0    NaN
          2010-05-09      F      1.0    NaN    5.0
```

---

If you have to merge many `DataFrames` it may be best to use `reduce` from functools.

```
from functools import reduce

merged_df = reduce(lambda l,r: l.merge(r, on=['SubjectID', 'Date'], how='outer', suffixes=['_l', '_r']), 
                   [df1, df2 ,df1, df2, df2])
```

You'll have lots of overlapping columns, but still can resolve them:

```
merged_df.groupby([x.split('_')[0] for x in merged_df.columns], 1).apply(lambda x: x.mode(1)[0])

         Date Gender  StudyID SubjectID  Test1  Test2
0  2010-05-08      M      1.0         A    1.0    1.0
1  2010-05-10      M      1.0         A    2.0    3.0
2  2010-05-08      M      1.0         B    3.0    4.0
3  2010-05-08      F      1.0         C    4.0    NaN
4  2010-05-09      M      1.0         A    NaN    2.0
5  2010-05-09      F      1.0         C    NaN    5.0
```

Comment: Thanks, both of these are good solutions. However, when I try to merge an odd number of dataframes, the `modal` solution returns an empty DataFrame, but produces the expected result when I merge an even number of dataframes. Any idea why this is the case?

Comment: @m42op64 see my update. I'm not entirely sure what is going wrong, perhaps the names are being messed up with multiple merges. Does my solution with `reduce` work for you? In my example, I specified 5 `DataFrames` to merge, and the resulting mode still works.